More efficient way to create new column in dataframe that uses row-based filtering but avoiding iterrows()
I have a function that is simplified below but that I use to create a new column in an existing dataframe. Right now I am using iterrows, but I tried using .apply while filtering by the unique groups of Year and Week (no these can not be converted to dates for reasons), but it did not speed it up much. Any ideas to use vectorized functions to accomplish this more efficiently?
Sample Versions:
input_df =



Year
Week
Company




2024
4
A


2023
18
A


2023
10
B



historical_df =



Year
Week
Company
Volume




2024
2
A
43


2023
16
A
32


2023
12
B
67



LOGIC
For each row in input_df:
-Filter historical_df based on Year, Week, and Company so that the calculation is only based each company's historical data based on that row's Year and Week.
-Sort historical data in order to use .head() to pull the 16 most recent weeks worth of data (only up to the current row's Year and Week)
-Use those (up to) 16 weeks worth of Volume data to calculate the coefficient of variability (st.dev / mean)
-Store that value in the list
-Use the list to create the new column in input_df
def add_variability(input_df, historical_df):
    variability_calcs = []

    for index, row in input_df.iterrows():
        filtered_historical_df = historical_df[
            ((historical_df['Year'] < row['Year']) |
            ((historical_df['Year'] == row['Year']) & (historical_df['Week'] < row['Week']))) & 
            (historical_df['Company'] == row['Company'])
        ]
    
        filtered_historical_df = filtered_historical_df.sort_values(by=['Year', 'Week'], ascending=False)

        recent_weeks = filtered_historical_df.head(16)

        if recent_weeks.shape[0] > 1:
            if recent_weeks['Volume'].mean() != 0:
                cv = recent_weeks['Volume'].std() / recent_weeks['Volume'].mean()
            else:
                cv = None
        else:
            cv = None
            
        variability_calcs.append(cv)
    
    input_df['Variability'] = variability_calcs
    return input_df

Output:
input_df =



Year
Week
Company
Variability




2024
4
A
0.334


2023
18
A
0.242


2023
10
B
0.455




Added sample dataframes and sample expected output.

We can only extrapolate so much based on sample I/O and code. Please describe what your program is supposed to do a little more clearly.

Your example function doesn't yield the shown output. Please make sure to provide a functional [mre].

It's not the calculation that is the issue, it is the filtering and usage of iterrows().

what about reshaping a bit your historical df with a rolling calculation like:
#sort your dataframe in a descending order 
histo_df = histo_df.sort_values(['Year',"Week"], ascending=False)
#then create a new column with your calculation rolling
histo_df['Variability'] = histo_df.groupby('Company')['Volume'].rolling(16).std() / histo_df.groupby('Company')['Volume'].rolling(16).mean()

and then you can merge or look into the historical dataframe the dates you want from your input_df

A good thing you can do initially when you're having performance issues with iterrows() is to switch to itertuples(), which is more performant and will require minimal changes to code.
Looking at your code, this probably isn't the main problem.  Looking at your logic it looks like you are filtering your entire source DF for every single row of your input df so as either of these dfs get more complicated your execution time will grow exponentially.
Some of your logic is redundant, though, and you could do some of the filtering once rather than again and again for every row. Ie you could separate each DataFrame so that each one only contains a single company and then loop through the pairs of dataframes.  You can also sort them at this point so you can use iloc to grab the appropriate 16 rows of data and eliminate those filtering steps as well.
I havent tested this extensively and it gets a different result than you list (which your snippet also does not get) but here is a cranked out example of this:
def add_variability(input_df, historical_df, window_size=16):
    # Group DataFrames by company
    input_df_grouped = input_df.groupby('Company')
    historical_df_grouped = historical_df.groupby('Company')

    variability_calcs = []

    for company, input_df_subset in input_df_grouped:
        historical_df_subset = historical_df_grouped.get_group(company)
        # Sort historical data within the loop
        historical_df_subset = historical_df_subset.sort_values(by=['Year', 'Week'], ascending=False)

        for row in input_df_subset.itertuples():
            # Use iloc to efficiently retrieve the {window_size} most recent rows
            recent_weeks = historical_df_subset.iloc[:window_size]

            if recent_weeks.shape[0] > 1:
                if recent_weeks['Volume'].mean() != 0:
                    cv = recent_weeks['Volume'].std() / recent_weeks['Volume'].mean()
                else:
                    cv = None
            else:
                cv = None

            variability_calcs.append(cv)

    input_df['Variability'] = variability_calcs
    return input_df

Edit:
Brain Fart.  The above solution contains an indexing error where it will only ever grab the top 16 rows of each df group.  Here is updated code:
def add_variability(input_df, historical_df, window_size=16):
    # Group DataFrames by company
    input_df_grouped = input_df.groupby('Company')
    historical_df_grouped = historical_df.groupby('Company')

    variability_calcs = []

    for company, input_df_subset in input_df_grouped:
        historical_df_subset = historical_df_grouped.get_group(company)
        # Sort historical data within the loop
        historical_df_subset = historical_df_subset.sort_values(by=['Year', 'Week'], ascending=False)

        for row in input_df_subset.itertuples():
            # Find the index of the current row's Year and Week
            index = historical_df_subset[(historical_df_subset['Year'] == row.Year) & (historical_df_subset['Week'] == row.Week)].index[0]
            # Retrieve the {window_size} rows up to and including the current row
            recent_weeks = historical_df_subset.iloc[index-window_size:index]

            if recent_weeks.shape[0] > 1:
                if recent_weeks['Volume'].mean() != 0:
                    cv = recent_weeks['Volume'].std() / recent_weeks['Volume'].mean()
                else:
                    cv = None
            else:
                cv = None

            variability_calcs.append(cv)

    input_df['Variability'] = variability_calcs
    return input_df

